# #file_links["C:\Frazes.txt",1,N]: #file_links["C:\Links.txt",1,N] recieve as a field data through gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I am using gravity form plugin into my wordpress site. Today I have received a query which contain these `#file_links["C:\Frazes.txt",1,N]: #file_links["C:\Links.txt",1,N]` lines into the email.

I have apply all the validation into my contact form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also receive similar queries regularly via my WordPress forms (I use wpforms). After a bit of research, these seem to be an attempt by a spammer to use the GSA software development kit (see their [manual here](https://docu.gsa-online.de/search_engine_ranker/macro_guide#spin_syntax_explained)) in order to generate a spam response to your form. However, in such cases the spammer didn't configure their spam macro correctly and therefore you see the spam macro (e.g. #file_links) instead of the actual spam content that would've been generated by that macro. You (and I!) should configure a good captcha in each form in order to block most of this spam. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to block these is to use the [BSK Gravity Forms Blacklist](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bsk-gravityforms-blacklist/) plugin. You can prevent submit of your form if the any of the fields contain the query, by creating a blacklist that checks any of the following items: Frazes.txt, #file_links, #file_links["C:\Frazes.txt",1,N]: #file_links["C:\Links.txt",1,N. Once you've created the blacklist, apply it to the email field (or any other field) in your form, make sure to choose the case-insensitive contains comparison. Hope this helps!